# Run anaconda virtual environment python with child_process

Tags: python, node.js, visual-studio-code, child-process, prophet

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const pythonOne = await spawn('C:/Users/lee/anaconda3/envs/test1/python.exe', ['./src/public/python/response.py', req.body.type, req.body.address]);
```

i want to run anaconda virtual environment python with spawn However, an error message is printed

**error message**

**C:\Users\lee\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy_*init*_.py:148: UserWarning: mkl-service package failed to import, therefore Intel(R) MKL initialization ensuring its correct out-of-the box operation under condition when Gnu OpenMP had already been loaded by Python process is not assured. Please install mkl-service package, see http://github.com/IntelPython/mkl-service
from . import *distributor_init
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\lee\OneDrive - �ܱ����б�\���� ȭ��\capston server-\app\src\public\python\response.py", line 4, in 
import pandas as pd
File "C:\Users\lee\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_*init**.py", line 16, in 
raise ImportError(
ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy:
IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!
Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.
We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:
https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html
Please note and check the following:

- The Python version is: Python3.9 from "C:\Users\lee\anaconda3\python.exe"
- The NumPy version is: "1.21.5"
  and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
  Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.
  Original error was: DLL load failed while importing _multiarray_umath: ������ ����� ã�� �� �����ϴ�.**

What's the problem?

Comment: Please provide enough information to be able to reproduce your problem.
Also according to your error message, it is recommended that you reinstall the `mkl-service` and `Numpy` packages.